# number field:How can i prove that ${\Bbb Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is a cyclotomic field?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

Can you help me with this ''simple'' exercise:

Prove that ${\Bbb Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is a cyclotomic field.

Answer (score 6):

A cyclotomic field is... And the complex roots of $x^3-1$ are...

Answer (score 3):

${\Bbb Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is a subfield of the field ${\Bbb Q}[ζ]$ where ζ is a root of $x^2+x+1$: $(-1+\sqrt(-3))/2)$ or $(-1-\sqrt(-3))/2)$. Since both fields have degree $2$, they both define the same field.